# jQuery Behavior/Execution Discrepancy Between Production and Development Server

Tags: javascript, jquery, amazon-web-services, lamp

I have a development and production server both running on LAMP in Ubuntu. When my browser runs a jQuery function on the development server I get expected results but when my browser runs the exact same jQuery on the production server, it fails to execute properly.

jQuery code in question:

```
$('.activeBlock').next('.previewBlock').not('.noDisplay').addClass('activeBlock');
$('.activeBlock').last().prev('.previewBlock').removeClass('activeBlock');
```

Before jQuery is executed:
[image]

After jQuery is executed on Development Server:
[image]

After jQuery is executed on Production Server:
[image]

Notice the class "activeBlock" has been added to #block2 and removed from #block1 on the development server but on the production server .activeBlock has just been added to #block2 and has not been removed from #block1.

Although this is a very specific example, I am seeing different results in other portions of my code as well but this provides just a clear example of my problem. I can verify that both the script and html are the exact same in both servers. Both servers are also hosted by Amazon Web Services and as far as I know are both running out-of-the-box LAMP configurations. Is it possible that one server is telling my browser to execute the code differently than the other server?

EDIT: No error or console messages are thrown in either situation

Comment: There are no ordinary circumstances under which the server can have any effect at all on how JavaScript is interpreted in browsers. It's not impossible, but it would be exceedingly strange.

Comment: Maybe you're loading different versions of your JavaScript code due to some sort of cache issue.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible but I'm stumped on why the two are behaving differently. It doesn't seem to make sense at all and I've looked at everything I can that relates this issue on SO and other forums and can't seem to find anything that could explain it.

Comment: Well the most likely thing is that the code is different, even though you think it isn't.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Refreshing with Ctrl + F5 clears the cache and forces the JS to reload doesn't it?

Comment: Well I have it set up through Git which should push and exact replica of my development server's code.

Comment: Are you loading this on to a shared server? Is the jQuery version the same? If it is shared, could someone else be running code that is interfering with your code? Are the servers clones of each other?

Comment: You can use the same URLs as the page(s) use to grab all the relevant JS files from both servers and checksum them.

Comment: One other person has access to the server but I can verify that I am the only one currently working on it. No they are not clones. There could be some differences in configuration somewhere.

Thanks, Pointy. That's a good idea I'll try it here in a bit and let you know if it changed anything!